# fopen get error with char * in c++

Tags: c++, c, char

There is a function to load files:

```
int loadfile(char *fn)
{
    printf( "\n my path: '%s' \n", fn );
    FILE *f = fopen( fn, "r");
    printf( "got\n" );

    ...

    return 1;
}
```

The first file is in main() `newfile( argv[1] );`, works. The second is get by flex parsing/reading the first file, what I belive isn't related to the problem.

The console:

```
path: 'file1.hot' 
got
path: 'file2.hot' 
Segmentation fault: 11
```

The printf was able to print the char *fn, but fopen get a segmentation fault.

The next situation was, I tried explicit to put the file inside the `loadfile` doing `fopen( "file2.hot", "r");` and works.

I'm compiling with g++, there is a different approaching when using c++ to use char * or fopen?

**EDIT**

Sorry, there's no `newfile( argv[1] );`. Correct: `loadfile( argv[1] );`.

Comment: For the error of segfault, you may have to give the full program, not a single function. The error is often not at where segfault pops up.

Comment: Any progress on finding the problem? Did you get around to try any of the suggested solutions yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General remark: When using C++, please prefer `std::fstream` to the C-style `fopen`/`fread`/etc.; also prefer `std::string` to `char*`. The latter alone will cure many memory headaches. If you, for some reason, have to stick to the C-style functions, be sure to check the return values (as mentioned in the other answers here already) - `fopen` for example returns a NULL pointer when it fails.

More specific to your question: Try to run your program under [gdb](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) (e.g. `gdb <your-program>`), to see where the Segmentation fault occurs exactly; that way you will also be able to see more details (e.g. variable contents etc.). Alternatively, if working under linux, use analysis tools such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to detect any kind of memory access problems.

Comment: More important, perhaps: prefer `std::string` to `char*`.  I'd be willing to bet that his problem is due to a buffer overrun when using `char*`.

Comment: Yes, I prefer, but this little part is in gnu-flex. I don't know if I can change to fstream and string.

Comment: 'I used to believe in printf, then I took a ...'. The problem was in another part as you, all, saying. I'm using gdb, correctly, now. I could not understand why the printf was not printed, because the real problem is far way from there.

Comment: It's probably because printf output is buffered; you'd have to call `fflush(stdout)` after each `printf` call to make it print at once as far as I can remember.

Answer (score 2):

Learn to use the [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/) debugger (assuming you are on Linux), or the [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) utility.
Perhaps putting your file path inside a [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/) is worthwhile, and, as *nyarlathotep* mentioned, use a [std::fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/).

It could happen that your `fn` is not null terminated....

Compile with `g++ -Wall -g`

As *Anders K* answered, always check the result of `fopen` against NULL. Pierre Vittet's [Talpo](http://gitorious.org/talpo/) extension to GCC (coded in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)) is able to check automatically that you do check that.

Comment: If the program has a segmentation fault while is loading the file, the problem can be in other point, and not there? The steps are print-name > fopen > print-got. If the print got was not printed, the problem can and cannot be between the prints? I compile as you say, the 0 point is `<????>` and the sequence is in another place where I couldn't figure out the connection.

Answer (score 2):

you should always check return values from functions that have a return value. In this case make sure when you fopen the file that the return handle is not NULL and also make sure if you open the file, to fclose it.